# Have a problem with Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 132

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

Controller

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    var users = adminDatabase.AspNetUsers.Where(u => u.UserName ==User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault();                                 
    Session["CurrentUser"] = users;
}
```

Connection

```
<add name = "DefaultConnection" 
     connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial  Catalog=administration;Integrated Security=SSPI"   
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

The problem that showed me is on controller user identity.

I have no idea what's going on!

Comment: How are you initializing adminDatabase ?

Comment: try .\\SQLEXPRESS in connectionString